# How to use multiple passes in HLSL?

Tags: c#, matlab, xna, hlsl

HLSL newbie question:

I'm trying to port the following MATLAB code to work on the graphics card.

```
function diff_im = anisodiff2D(im, num_iter, delta_t, kappa, option)
im = double(im);

% PDE (partial differential equation) initial condition.
diff_im = im;

% Center pixel distances.
dx = 1;
dy = 1;
dd = sqrt(2);

% 2D convolution masks - finite differences.
hN = [0 1 0; 0 -1 0; 0 0 0];
hS = [0 0 0; 0 -1 0; 0 1 0];
hE = [0 0 0; 0 -1 1; 0 0 0];
hW = [0 0 0; 1 -1 0; 0 0 0];
hNE = [0 0 1; 0 -1 0; 0 0 0];
hSE = [0 0 0; 0 -1 0; 0 0 1];
hSW = [0 0 0; 0 -1 0; 1 0 0];
hNW = [1 0 0; 0 -1 0; 0 0 0];

% Anisotropic diffusion.
for t = 1:num_iter

        % Finite differences. [imfilter(.,.,'conv') can be replaced by conv2(.,.,'same')]
        nablaN = imfilter(diff_im,hN,'conv');
        nablaS = imfilter(diff_im,hS,'conv');   
        nablaW = imfilter(diff_im,hW,'conv');
        nablaE = imfilter(diff_im,hE,'conv');   
        nablaNE = imfilter(diff_im,hNE,'conv');
        nablaSE = imfilter(diff_im,hSE,'conv');   
        nablaSW = imfilter(diff_im,hSW,'conv');
        nablaNW = imfilter(diff_im,hNW,'conv'); 

        % Diffusion function.
        if option == 1
            cN = exp(-(nablaN/kappa).^2);
            cS = exp(-(nablaS/kappa).^2);
            cW = exp(-(nablaW/kappa).^2);
            cE = exp(-(nablaE/kappa).^2);
            cNE = exp(-(nablaNE/kappa).^2);
            cSE = exp(-(nablaSE/kappa).^2);
            cSW = exp(-(nablaSW/kappa).^2);
            cNW = exp(-(nablaNW/kappa).^2);
        elseif option == 2
            cN = 1./(1 + (nablaN/kappa).^2);
            cS = 1./(1 + (nablaS/kappa).^2);
            cW = 1./(1 + (nablaW/kappa).^2);
            cE = 1./(1 + (nablaE/kappa).^2);
            cNE = 1./(1 + (nablaNE/kappa).^2);
            cSE = 1./(1 + (nablaSE/kappa).^2);
            cSW = 1./(1 + (nablaSW/kappa).^2);
            cNW = 1./(1 + (nablaNW/kappa).^2);
        end

        % Discrete PDE solution.
        diff_im = diff_im + ...
                  delta_t*(...
                  (1/(dy^2))*cN.*nablaN + (1/(dy^2))*cS.*nablaS + ...
                  (1/(dx^2))*cW.*nablaW + (1/(dx^2))*cE.*nablaE + ...
                  (1/(dd^2))*cNE.*nablaNE + (1/(dd^2))*cSE.*nablaSE + ...
                  (1/(dd^2))*cSW.*nablaSW + (1/(dd^2))*cNW.*nablaNW );

        % Iteration warning.
        fprintf('\rIteration %d\n',t);
end
```

It the moment I have it working with one pass:

```
texture2D Input0;
sampler2D Input0Sampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <Input0>;
    MinFilter = Point;
    MagFilter = Point;
    MipFilter = Point;
    AddressU = Clamp;
    AddressV = Clamp;
};

struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float2 TextureCoordinate : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float2 TextureCoordinate : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct PixelShaderOutput
{
    // TODO: Optionally add/remove output indices to match GPUProcessor.numOutputs
    float4 Index0 : COLOR0;
};

// input texture dimensions
static float w = 1920 - 8;
static float h = 1080 - 8;

static const float2 pixel = float2(1.0 / w, 1.0 / h);
static const float2 halfPixel = float2(pixel.x / 2, pixel.y / 2);

static const float3x3 hN =
{
    0,  1, 0,
    0, -1, 0,
    0,  0, 0
};
static const float3x3 hS =
{
    0,  0, 0,
    0, -1, 0,
    0,  1, 0
};
static const float3x3 hE =
{
    0,  0, 0,
    0, -1, 1,
    0,  0, 0
};
static const float3x3 hW =
{
    0,  0, 0,
    1, -1, 0,
    0,  0, 0
};
static const float3x3 hNE =
{
    0,  0, 1,
    0, -1, 0,
    0,  0, 0
};
static const float3x3 hSE =
{
    0,  0, 0,
    0, -1, 0,
    0,  0, 1
};
static const float3x3 hSW =
{
    0,  0, 0,
    0, -1, 0,
    1,  0, 0
};
static const float3x3 hNW =
{
    1,  0, 0,
    0, -1, 0,
    0,  0, 0
};

VertexShaderOutput VertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderInput vsInput)
{
    //VertexShaderOutput output;

    //output.Position = vsInput.Position;
    //output.TextureCoordinate = vsInput.TextureCoordinate;

    VertexShaderOutput output;
    vsInput.Position.x =  vsInput.Position.x - 2*halfPixel.x;
    vsInput.Position.y =  vsInput.Position.y + 2*halfPixel.y;
    output.Position = vsInput.Position;
    output.TextureCoordinate = vsInput.TextureCoordinate ;
    return output;

    //return output;
}

float4 Convolution(VertexShaderOutput input, float3x3 kernel)
{
    //PixelShaderOutput output;
    float4 pixel = float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    for (int i = -1; i <= 1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; ++j)
        {
            pixel += kernel[i+1][j+1] * tex2D(Input0Sampler, input.TextureCoordinate + float2(i,j));
        };
    };

    return pixel;
}

PixelShaderOutput PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput psInput)
{       
    PixelShaderOutput output;
    output.Index0 = tex2D(Input0Sampler, psInput.TextureCoordinate);

    float dx, dy, dd;
    dx = 1; dy = 1; dd = pow(2, 0.5);
    float delta_t = 1/7;


    float4 nablaN = Convolution(psInput, hN);
    float4 nablaS = Convolution(psInput, hS);
    float4 nablaW = Convolution(psInput, hW);
    float4 nablaE = Convolution(psInput, hE);
    float4 nablaNE = Convolution(psInput, hNE);
    float4 nablaSE = Convolution(psInput, hSE);
    float4 nablaSW = Convolution(psInput, hSW);
    float4 nablaNW = Convolution(psInput, hNW);

    float4 cN  = 1 / pow( 1 + (nablaN / 40), 2);
    float4 cS  = 1 / pow( 1 + (nablaS / 40), 2);
    float4 cW  = 1 / pow( 1 + (nablaW / 40), 2);
    float4 cE  = 1 / pow( 1 + (nablaE / 40), 2);
    float4 cNE = 1 / pow( 1 + (nablaNE / 40), 2);
    float4 cSE = 1 / pow( 1 + (nablaSE / 40), 2);
    float4 cSW = 1 / pow( 1 + (nablaSW / 40), 2);
    float4 cNW = 1 / pow( 1 + (nablaNW / 40), 2);   

    output.Index0 += delta_t * 
    (
        mul(cN, nablaN) + mul(cS, nablaS) + mul(cW, nablaW) + mul(cE, nablaE) + (dd*dd)*(mul(cNE, nablaNE) + mul(cSE, nablaSE) + mul(cSW, nablaSW) + mul(cNW, nablaNW))
    );

    return output;

}

technique PeronaMalik
{
    pass pass1
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 VertexShaderFunction();
        PixelShader  = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```

The problem is I need this technique to be applied several times succesively as in the matlab code.
Should I even be using multiple passes to do this?

**EDIT**

if I decide to use C# to controll the passes then I could try:

```
byte[] theBytes = TemplateMatch.Bytes;
for (int iters = 0; iters < 3; iters++)
{
    t.SetData<byte>(theBytes);
    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renOutput);

    effect.Parameters["Input0"].SetValue(t);
    quad.RenderFullScreenQuad(effect);
    for (int i = 0; i < effect.Techniques.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < effect.Techniques[i].Passes.Count; j++)
        {
            effect.Techniques[i].Passes[j].Apply();
        }
    }

    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

    renOutput.GetData<float>(arrayOutput);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(arrayOutput, 0, theBytes, 0, theBytes.Length);
}
```

But on the second iteration I get an error

> You may not call SetData on a resource while it is actively set on the
>   GraphicsDevice. Unset it from the device before calling SetData.

on line t.SetData(theBytes);

**EDIT**

I've tried

```
byte[] theBytes = TemplateMatch.Bytes;
for (int iters = 0; iters < 3; iters++)
{                    
    t.SetData<byte>(theBytes);
    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renOutput);

    effect.Parameters["Input0"].SetValue(t);
    quad.RenderFullScreenQuad(effect);
    for (int i = 0; i < effect.Techniques.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < effect.Techniques[i].Passes.Count; j++)
        {
            effect.Techniques[i].Passes[j].Apply();
        }
    }

    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

    renOutput.GetData<float>(arrayOutput);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(arrayOutput, 0, theBytes, 0, theBytes.Length);
    GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = null;
}
```

this seems to fix the runtime error but this gives me the same un-filtered image!

**EDIT**

I've modified the above matlab code so that it runs in freemat. I've stepped through the code and I've found that the problem is related to the lines like this cN = exp(-(nablaN/kappa).^2);
In the freemat version these do not evaluate to zeros (while my HLSL version does). This leads me to suspect that the problem is related to precision issues with HLSL or how I'm handling floating point arithmetic on the graphics card.

Comment: I now  believe that the reason for my image not being transformed is an issue which is better delt with on digital signal processing rather than stack overflow.

Comment: If anyone's got an explanation for GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = null; I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: I think this is relevant http://www.gamedev.net/topic/636388-float-precision-difference-between-hlsl-and-glsl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying the pass but don¡t draw anything.

At least you should have the code similar to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < effect.Techniques.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < effect.Techniques[i].Passes.Count; j++)
    {
        effect.Techniques[i].Passes[j].Apply();
        quad.RenderFullScreenQuad(effect); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using quads to render the image. My problem was fixed by GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = null; although I'm not sure why this fixes it. I'm also not sure if its the best way to fix it.

Comment: You can't get/set data from/to a texture set in the device